# Path on the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

> Prove that the following map is smooth and analyse its image as the real number $\alpha$ varies (how does it look like? Is it a submanifold?)
>
> \begin{align*} 
> f_{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}&\to\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1\\
> t&\mapsto (e^{2\pi it}, e^{2\pi \alpha it})
> \end{align*}

I've managed to prove that $f_{\alpha}$ is smooth and that $\text{Im}(f_{\alpha})$ is a closed curve on the torus $\Leftrightarrow \alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$. But I'm having trouble to formalize whether or not it is a submanifold of the torus. I actually don't know if it is true when the image is not a closed curve. How can I solve this?

Comment: What's your definition of a submanifold? Do you require it to be a closed subspace?

Comment: I'm considering a submanifold as just a subset of the torus which is also a manifold itself. Intuitively, I belive the closed curve is a submanifold, but otherwise, I can barely visualize the picture, so it's hard to have a hunch

Answer (score 3):

Should it be $f_{\alpha}(t)=(e^{2\pi i t}, e^{2\pi \alpha i t})$ ?

**If so,** sure it is a manifold when $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ (with the proper identification it is simply a curve on $\mathbb R^2$. In this case, it is a curve that spirals around the torus until it closes, much like in the figure:

[image]

When $\alpha\not\in\mathbb Q$ the curve is dense in the torus.

Since rational numbers and irrational numbers are dense, it is difficult to say much more about what happens when $\alpha$ varies.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the exponents, just corrected it. About the density when $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}$, that's what got me unsettled. It just sounds weird to talk about a 1-submanifold which is dense in a 2-manifold. Very conter intuitive to me

Comment: You are right, but that's why it is only a manifold when $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that my intuition was right! But how would I actually prove it isn't a manifold? Any hint would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Locally your manifold should be like a line segment. How could that be if it is dense? Any neighborhood will have much more than just a segment and that's all you need to say.

Comment: @Jonas Btw, where did you get this nice illustration?

Comment: Somewhere from the web, entering "geodesics" and "torus". I am not able to do it with Mathematica...

Comment: Source found: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be irrational then we know the set $\{m+n\alpha|m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is dense in $ \mathbb{R}$. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and for given $\delta >0 $ there exists $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|x \alpha-y+m+n\alpha|< \delta$. We have $||(e^{2 \pi ix},e^{2 \pi iy})-(e^{2 \pi i(x+n)},e^{2\pi i(x+n)\alpha} )||$=$|1-e^{2 \pi i(x \alpha-y +m+\alpha n)}| $. Since exponential function is continuous at zero for given any $\epsilon >0$ we can bound the quantity with that. Hence, it is dense.

Comment: You have posted the [same answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3911816/) to two different questions. When you do this, it creates noise on the website. If you believe that two questions have the same answer, then you should flag one as a duplicate of the other, and only post one answer.